# How to run an SSIS package having excel source on a server where excel is not installed using SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package that reads data using a custom query and stores it into a target excel source. I am able to run the SSIS package successfully on a server where no excel is installed by doing a right click and selecting the Run Package option. When I add the same SSIS package to Integration services and run the package, it still executes successfully. But, when I schedule the package using SQL Server agent job, it fails with the below error:

"Executed as user: Username. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved. Argument "Excel" for option "connection" is not valid. The command line parameters are invalid. The step failed."

Specification of SQL Server: SQL SERVER 2008 R2
 Executing as SQL Server Agent Job.

Tried the following:
 1) Checked the 'Use 32 bit' check box under Execution options tab in Step menu and unchecked all the check boxes in Datasources tab. Got the below error:

"**Executed as user: Username. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved. Started: 9:44:03 PM Error: 2015-06-08 21:44:04.21 Code: 0xC002F304 Source: File System Task File System Task Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "The device is not ready. ". End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started: 9:44:03 PM Finished: 9:44:04 PM Elapsed: 1.219 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed."**

2) Created a proxy account that had sysadmin, public, serveradmin roles. Modelled the package to run as proxy account. Got the below error:

**"Executed as user: Username. The process could not be created for step 1 of job (reason: 1314). The step failed."
 The command line looks almost similar to the below:
 /DTS "\File System\PackageName" /SERVER SERVERNAME /CONNECTION "InputFileConn.xlsx";"F:\Folder\InputFile.xlsx" /CONNECTION "OutputFileConn.xlsx 1";"F:\Folder\Output\OutputFile.xlsx" /CONNECTION "Excel Connection Manager 1";"\"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Folder\Output\OutputFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES"";\"" /CONNECTION "SERVERINSTANCE.DBName";"\"Data Source=ServerInstance;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-Package-{D4E09BF5-DF25-3DE7-BCAE-B667C38F85B7}SERVERNAME\SQLSERVER.DatabaseName;\"" /X86 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E**

Is it necessary to install excel in the server to make the SQL Server agent job work?

Comment: When you right click/run package is it in the SSIS Service? This is a common misperception. It is **not** running on the server it is running locally. Your problem is more likely to be that the Excel file is not found at the location _when considered from the local server_. i.e. is there an F drive on the server? The first step in solving this is using a UNC rather than a drive name.

Comment: I verified your points and I can see that they are all in place. Is it necessary to install excel in the server to make the SQL Server agent job work?

Comment: No it isn't. It might be necessary to install a _driver_ though. With an error like 'the device is not ready', it is far more likely this is a path error not an installation error. If you believe you have verified this then I can't help any further, but I strongly suggest you try using a UNC, not a drive letter. The fact that it works locally with F drive and doesn't on the server is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Apologies I dint verify properly .. I didn't test it. Yes.. You are ryt. That fixed the issue . Thanks  a lot for your help. Also  we found that its working in the test server as access engine is installed in it. But my unanswered question is  Is it necessary to install excel in the server to make the SQL Server agent job work?

Comment: Unless the SQL Agent Job is in turn calling some special scripting that requires the Excel object model to be installed, no you don't need to install Excel. When importing and exporting data, the `ACE` or `Jet` driver will be used (you'll see these mentioned in the package. These drivers are already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion above, the job was referring to F drive but F is a different drive to expected when running on the server.